# mysql remote hosting

Tags: mysql, jsp, hosting, localhost

Hello I have hosted a small webpage (JSP+Mysql) on Eatj.com for trial offer of 15 days.My problem is that database connection on localhost is successful but after hosting my connection string is giving exception.
code:

```
try{
  String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://pulicipaddress/dbname"; 

  Connection con= null; 
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "eatjid", "eatjpassword");
...
```

it says that my connection not defined.

Comment: where have you specified the port? It should be `jdbc:mysql://pulicipaddress:port/dbname`

Comment: which port 3306 or the remote port shown by ipchicken

Comment: don't know what ipchicken is. I am talking about 3306 port

Comment: and which id password should i use my root data or one of the hosting website

Comment: not your local one, the one that your provider gave you

Answer (score 0):

If both the JSP and the database are hosted at eatj.com I'd expect you to have obtained database login information from eatj.com. I suppose - as with most hosters - the database is not accessible from the "outside", so it must be some internal server name.

Also, it wouldn't make sense to access the database through the public address when both the database and the code accessing the database are running in the hosted environment.

Usually, in hosted environments, things work like this:

```
                      +- "hoster only" ----------------+
External Viewer ----> | JSP-Code ----> Database Server |
                      +--------------------------------+
```

The external viewer requests the web page created by the JSP, the JSP does everything in the "hoster only" environment.

Comment: i don't know that if both are hosted or not.I am just asked to upload the ROOT.war file which I create in DOS.

Comment: one of the rules dispalyed in EATJ reads as follows: If you use a database, you have to use a database connection pool. For sample connection pool code, you can download sample.zip (check DBConnector.java and DBUtil.java) You not only save resources, but also improve your application performance by using a connection pool. The maximum number of concurrent connections is 10.

Comment: If the database was not hosted, where should it be stored otherwise? I suggest you download the sample and check how they do things by reading their documentation also.